# Why does Visual Studio show "Push" rather than "Publish" for a new git branch created locally?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm confused by something in the [Visual Studio Team Services documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/git/tutorial/pushing?tabs=visual-studio#share-your-code-with-push) relating to git push:

> In Team Explorer, open the Sync view. The view lists outgoing commits
>   and will present you with one of two links to push them to your remote
>   repo: Publish when there is not a branch on the remote repo associated
>   with the current local branch. This will create a branch with the same
>   name on the remote repo and push the commits to it. Later you will
>   Push, not publish changes when using this branch since the
>   relationship between the branch on the local branch and the remote
>   repo exists. Push when there is a relationship between the local
>   branch and the remote repo. Clicking this will push the commits to the
>   remote branch.

Yet when I create a new local branch that is not tracking a remote repo, I see the "Push" link and not the "Publish" link:

[image: new branch not showing publish command]

Why does the link say "Push" and not "Publish"?

Comment: `push` is standard git terminology for sharing history.

Comment: Yes, that's clearly true, @evolutionxbox, but also not the question being asked.  The question is about whether the documentation is correct and matches the functionality of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio 2017 Microsoft is working hard to align on naming and constructs to be more aligned with the standard Git terminology. The naming in the docs reflects the Visual Studio 2013-2015 UI.

Given the documentation states it covers TFS 2015-2018 and VS2015-10217 there is currently no one-way to document this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case! Just to clarify, "Push" does the same thing that "Publish" is supposed to do, i.e. creates a new remote branch and pushes the commit.

Comment: It does. It was originally thought to be confusing for non-git users. But with more and more people making the switch, it became more confusing for git-users ;).